# How do I rewrite same record in DB?

Tags: c#, sqlite

this code always adds a new record into DB.
Could someone help me?
How do I rewrite a single record with a new value.

```
 public void SaveIntoDB_method()
        {
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString, true))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "REPLACE INTO Grocery(Seafood) VALUES(@Seafood);";                   
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seafood", Seafood);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

[image]

```
 public async void Requery_method()
        {
            try
            {

                using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString, true))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())

                    {

                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Grocery;";
                        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // how to read out here back to Seafood property?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Another question.
How do I read out value back to Seafood property?

**todays:**
Read out different rows to different properties, the column is the same.
This works.I don't know if it is made properly.

```
 public async void Requery_method()
        {

            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString, true))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync(); 

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())

                {
                    // read out a record with id=1
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Grocery WHERE ID = 1;";
                    var reader1 = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                    if (reader1.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (await reader1.ReadAsync())
                        {


                            Seafood_at_store1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader1)["Seafood"]);

                        }

                    }

                    reader1.Close();


                    // read out a record with id=2
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Grocery WHERE ID = 2;";
                    var reader2 = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                    if (reader2.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (await reader2.ReadAsync())
                        {

                            Seafood_at_store2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader2)["Seafood"]);

                        }

                    }


                    reader2.Close();

                }


            }


        }
```

Comment: Use `UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE INTO`? REPLACE INTO only replaces when a primary key or unique constraint violation occurs. If you don't have such a situation, a new row will be inserted and this is by design.

Comment: If you have another question you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, the **REPLACE** statement is used to delete and reinsert existing rows. The REPLACE command in SQLite is an alias for the INSERT OR REPLACE variant of the INSERT command.

Try this instead

*** **Always use where condition when updating**

```
 command.CommandText =
            "update Grocery set Seafood = @Seafood where Seafood = '123'";//This will update grocery table where seafood = 123.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seafood", Seafood); 
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And here is how to read multiple results

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Grocery WHERE ID IN( 1, 2)";
                var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                var groceryList = New List<int>();// Need a list grocery object to avoid duplicating code.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    
                    var seaFood = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Seafood"]);
                     groceryList.add(grocery);
                }
```

Comment: first, thanks for the valuable code, the only thing I  changed is : "Add" I  replaced with "AddWithValue", Since "Add" has issued a fail, for some reasons.

Comment: you have missed "h" there )

Comment: I've added a question on requery method.Please see first post.

Comment: while (reader.Read())
            {
                var seafood = reader.GetInt32(0); OR reader[0]
            }

Comment: (0) or [0]  meaning in this case?

Comment: The column number

Comment: Perhaps you know how to UPDATE a certain record but same Column? For example "Seafood" has got two records. So how do I UPDATE the second one?

Comment: How many columns your table contains? You can use where condition. For ex: Update grocery... Where anothercolumn = value.  If your tables has only one column you have to update using the old value as condition. For ex: Update grocery set seafood = @seafood Where seafood = currentvalue.

Comment: The table has got one Column called "Seafood". Please help with sample-code. How to UPDATE, e.g. another record for "Seafood". For example "Seafood" has got two records. How do I UPDATE each record separately.Thanks.

Comment: I edited the original answer with where clause. This should work.

Comment: I don't undestand how does your code know which record should be updated.

Comment: It will run through the whole records, if a record match the where condition, this record will be updated. For ex: Where seafood = '456'. If my table has three rows with seafood = '123, seafood = '456' and seafood = '999'. Only the second record will be updated.

Comment: Ah... simple I thought that I should put somehow a record number in the code. OK, when the table is newly created and all records have zero values or same ones? What then?

Comment: If your table has no rows, the update command will be executed exactly in the same way, but the executer will find no rows matching the condition, if ALL rows have the same value, ALL rows will be updated. Thats why it is a good practice to have a column to represent the Record Id. And If you execute a select, no rows will be returned. Sorry If my english contains some mistakes, my cellphone use portuguese as default language.

Comment: Finally, we have come to ID. For example, I created ID column and "Seafood' has got two records now. So how the sql-command  is going to look if I will need to write value into ID =2 (second row)  of "Seafood" column.

Comment: Update grocery set seafood =@seafood where id = @id then command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 2)

Comment: Thanks, that looks workable. I will try tomorrow. Goodnight

Comment: Hi, yesterday you wrote ```while (reader.Read()) { var seafood = reader.GetInt32(0);``` . OK, how do I read from a particular record? For example from a record with id =2?

Comment: Select * from grocery where id = 2.   Just one remark, avoid using *. Always try to use field name. Ex: select seafood, id from grocery where id = 2.

Comment: Right now, I've come across with such a behaviour.   ```cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 2);  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 4);  ``` I want to write in two records simultaneously at same method. It doesn't work. It works either for id=2 or id=4. Simultaneous writing doesnt work, for some reasons.

Comment: Ah, found by myself. After each command block it must be put ```ExecuteNoneQuery();```, otherwise the preceding command won't be executed. So for two command blocks must be two ```ExecuteNoneQuery();```

Comment: Well, to read from a record with id=2 and id id=4. Should I make two different readers? As follows: `while (await reader1.ReadAsync()){}`  and `while (await reader2.ReadAsync()){}`?

Comment: For two records, you dont need two executions. You can use IN clause. Ex: select * from grocery where id IN (2, 4).  The same goes to update.

Comment: Ok, I don't need multiple `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Grocery WHERE ID = 4;";`  Then what about reader?  I read out a record(4columns) with id=1 to respective properties. I read out a record(4columns) with id=4 to another respective propeties.

Comment: I edited the post. But basically, you will loop through the rows result inside the while. Each row you need to pass to a object and the object you add inside a list.

Comment: at first post I've put working piece of code. It marked as **todays**. Could you look at this and make a correction? The major point of this is a fetching data from different rows to different propertries while having same the column.

Comment: Tiago, how do I communicate with you at another place?